# Drawing a line that is always parallel the ground on Android

Tags: android, rotation

I'm doing a little experiment in my app and I'm trying to draw a line that would move/rotate so that it's always parallel the ground. So for example if the phone is tilted by 45 degrees, the line is rotated by 45 degrees the opposite direction.

This is my current implementation:

I'm using `OrientationEventListener` to get the orientation change. The data I get looks something like this:

```
01-21 18:20:51.783 28956-28956/com.myapp.test D/DeviceOrientationManager: .onOrientationChanged() - entered - 300
01-21 18:20:51.848 28956-28956/com.myapp.test D/DeviceOrientationManager: .onOrientationChanged() - entered - 289
01-21 18:20:51.912 28956-28956/com.myapp.test D/DeviceOrientationManager: .onOrientationChanged() - entered - 283
01-21 18:20:52.042 28956-28956/com.myapp.test D/DeviceOrientationManager: .onOrientationChanged() - entered - 278
01-21 18:20:52.109 28956-28956/com.myapp.test D/DeviceOrientationManager: .onOrientationChanged() - entered - 272
01-21 18:20:52.173 28956-28956/com.myapp.test D/DeviceOrientationManager: .onOrientationChanged() - entered - 266
01-21 18:20:52.237 28956-28956/com.myapp.test D/DeviceOrientationManager: .onOrientationChanged() - entered - 261
01-21 18:20:52.302 28956-28956/com.myapp.test D/DeviceOrientationManager: .onOrientationChanged() - entered - 255
01-21 18:20:52.366 28956-28956/com.myapp.test D/DeviceOrientationManager: .onOrientationChanged() - entered - 252
01-21 18:20:52.430 28956-28956/com.myapp.test D/DeviceOrientationManager: .onOrientationChanged() - entered - 248
01-21 18:20:52.560 28956-28956/com.myapp.test D/DeviceOrientationManager: .onOrientationChanged() - entered - 246
01-21 18:20:52.690 28956-28956/com.myapp.test D/DeviceOrientationManager: .onOrientationChanged() - entered - 248
01-21 18:20:52.755 28956-28956/com.myapp.test D/DeviceOrientationManager: .onOrientationChanged() - entered - 251
01-21 18:20:52.819 28956-28956/com.myapp.test D/DeviceOrientationManager: .onOrientationChanged() - entered - 254
01-21 18:20:52.883 28956-28956/com.myapp.test D/DeviceOrientationManager: .onOrientationChanged() - entered - 258
01-21 18:20:52.949 28956-28956/com.myapp.test D/DeviceOrientationManager: .onOrientationChanged() - entered - 260
01-21 18:20:53.016 28956-28956/com.myapp.test D/DeviceOrientationManager: .onOrientationChanged() - entered - 264
01-21 18:20:53.079 28956-28956/com.myapp.test D/DeviceOrientationManager: .onOrientationChanged() - entered - 267
01-21 18:20:53.145 28956-28956/com.myapp.test D/DeviceOrientationManager: .onOrientationChanged() - entered - 274
01-21 18:20:53.208 28956-28956/com.myapp.test D/DeviceOrientationManager: .onOrientationChanged() - entered - 277
01-21 18:20:53.273 28956-28956/com.myapp.test D/DeviceOrientationManager: .onOrientationChanged() - entered - 281
01-21 18:20:53.337 28956-28956/com.myapp.test D/DeviceOrientationManager: .onOrientationChanged() - entered - 284
01-21 18:20:53.403 28956-28956/com.myapp.test D/DeviceOrientationManager: .onOrientationChanged() - entered - 289
01-21 18:20:53.467 28956-28956/com.myapp.test D/DeviceOrientationManager: .onOrientationChanged() - entered - 293
01-21 18:20:53.532 28956-28956/com.myapp.test D/DeviceOrientationManager: .onOrientationChanged() - entered - 298
01-21 18:20:53.855 28956-28956/com.myapp.test D/DeviceOrientationManager: .onOrientationChanged() - entered - 295
```

As it's visible from this data, there is no consistency when I get a new orientation. Another issue is that the orientation can 'skip' some steps and jump by any number of degrees.

After some calculation to determine by how much I need to rotate my line, I use the following for rotation:

```
mLine.animate().setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator()).rotation(
            degrees).setDuration(60);
```

And this works ok as doing animate() on the View allows me to cancel previous animation and resume from the same point towards the new rotation value. However the line feels a bit wobbly and sluggish. If I rotate the device slowly, the line looks ok, however if I rotate more vigorously, it gets a bit of a delay. I think this is related to the duration of the rotation that I'm setting and a faster rotation of the phone should lower the duration I'm using for the animation.. However I'm not really sure how to calculate that and all I've tried only made the situation worse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `OrientationEventListener`, you should instead use the [Rotation Vector Sensor](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html#sensors-motion-rotate). This sensor gives you realtime sensor data in a coordinate system that is in relation to gravity:

> - X is defined as the vector product Y x Z. It is tangential to the ground at the device's current location and points approximately East.
> - Y is tangential to the ground at the device's current location and points toward the geomagnetic North Pole.
> - Z points toward the sky and is perpendicular to the ground plane.

Therefore the angle you are looking for is the angle from the X axis.

```
private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private Sensor mSensor;
...
mSensorManager = 
    (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
mSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR);
```